# Updating meshes inside arrays in react three fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I have an array of roundedBox gemoetry (myShape)
and I want to know if I can change the position of one of the shapes inside the array,
I can replace it the shape at the index I want with a new one with the position I want,
but this isn't good, 
I don't want to create a new one, I only want to update the position of the already existing one, and update it on the canvas.
here's what I have:
This is what I wanna do: shapes[1].props.position = [150, 0, 150]

```
const [shapes, setShapes] = useState([<MyShape key={0} position={[0, 0, 0]} />, <MyShape key={1} position={[100, 0, 100]} />, <MyShape key={2} position={[200, 0, 200]} />])
useEffect(() => {
  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.key === 'r') {
      shapes[1] = <MyShape key={1} position={[150, 0, 150]} />
      // shapes[1].props.position = [150, 0, 150];
      setShapes([...shapes]);
      console.log(shapes)
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
  }
}, [shapes])

return (
  <group >
    {[...shapes]}
  </group>
)
```

Comment: Hi, I would suggest that instead of storing elements in your state, maybe it is better to store the positions instead. Also you shouldn't directly mutate state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shapes[1] = <MyShape key={1} position={[150, 0, 150]} />
```

This line in your code directly modify the state which is a bad idea. You can read more about it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/prgsel/why_is_it_bad_idea_to_mutate_state_directly/).

---

I would suggest that instead of storing elements in your state. Just store the position in your state instead.

I have not tested this but it will probably look something like this:

```
const [positions, setPositions] = useState([
  [0, 0, 0],
  [100, 0, 100],
  [200, 0, 200],
]);

useEffect(() => {
  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.key === 'r') {
      setPositions((prevPositions) => {
        const newPositions = [...prevPositions];
        // You might want to check for null index here.
        newPositions[1] = [150, 0, 150];
        return newPositions;
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
  };
}, [shapes]);

return (
  <group>
    {positions.map((position, idx) => (
      // Using idx here for simplicity purposes.
      <MyShape key={idx} position={position} />
    ))}
  </group>
);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, Thank you!